# Expand div while content grows

Tags: html

I have the following CSS code here:
http://pastebin.com/EnNLzabw

```
#maincontent {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("http://www.viasat.se/sites/all/themes/viasat/images/grey-bg.png");
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 252px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 9px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

And I've got this HTML:
http://pastebin.com/0P5YDJzj

```
<div id="maincontent">
  <h2>Produkter</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://91.90.24.136/gymexperten/images/pic2.png">
      <h4>Swedish Supplements F#cked Up</h4>
      <div class="cartbutton">Lägg till</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://91.90.24.136/gymexperten/images/pic1.png">
      <h4>Self Omninutrition Whey Shake 3kg</h4>
      <div class="cartbutton">Lägg till</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://91.90.24.136/gymexperten/images/pic3.png">
      <h4>Optimum Nutrition Platinum Pre</h4>
      <div class="cartbutton">Lägg till</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://91.90.24.136/gymexperten/images/pic4.png">
      <h4>Optimum Nutrition 100% Whey Gold Standard 450g</h4>
      <div class="cartbutton">Lägg till</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://www.proteinbolaget.se/shop/thumbnails/shop/26329/art29/h9635/21549635-origpic-5c59fc.png_0_0_100_100_172_160_85.png">
      <h4>BMR Sports Nutrition Duzixon 180 kapslar</h4>
      <div class="cartbutton">Lägg till</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The maincontent dosen't want to expand, while more content is added. I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Post the code in your question.

Comment: post your code here, so we can guess the problem to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is expanding just fine. You have overflow: hidden set on #maincontent and your content is overflowing that and becoming hidden.

As far as I can tell, the major fixes you need are:

```
.box {
  /* remove this ---> position: absolute */
  /* use one of these instead: */
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
}

/* pick one of these to fix your image that is way too large */
#banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
#banner {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Well, that did not solve my problem. The maincontent still not expand on the height.

Comment: @user500468 you have a lot of css issues. See my updated answer and study how to use `float` or `display` to achieve the layout you're looking for. `position: absolute` should never be used for a purpose like that.

Comment: I must use position:absolute; because when I hover a div, the content in .box is expanded in height, and it affects the divs below the hovered div. I use z-index to make the hovered div appear upon the div below.

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/vVm85/

Comment: @user500468 you can use `absolute` on the part that expands. There's no need to use it on the parent.

Comment: What do u mean? I use absolute on .box, which expands when it's hovered.

Comment: @user500468 see this http://jsbin.com/uBaWuLeV/1/edit The expanded content doesn't affect anything else. This is one of many ways it can be accomplished.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your comment. Do you want your code to work or not? Putting `position: absolute` on those elements is bad. This is obvious because of the result you're getting. I've shown you a better way. If you don't want your code to better, then why did you ask how to fix it?

Comment: Lovley! Thank u soo much! Can u explain a little how the CSS works in your demo? :-)

Comment: @user500468 Easy stuff. `display: inline-block` elements will line up next to each other if there is room. `position: absolute` elements don't affect anything else around them and they are relative to the closest parent element with `position: relative`. Those three rules are the important ones. Here's the most basic version: http://jsbin.com/uBaWuLeV/3/edit Just note that you can't see the bottom expanded content because it goes off the page. You would need a footer or padding underneath to fix that.